# Deleting database entries and AngularJS. Should I throw an exception if an entry can't be deleted?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, exception

So I have an AngualrJS application that is acting as a single-page-application (SPA). This SPA is using an existing Rails API to make xhr requests which returns entries from the database as JSON.

I am currently trying to write some code to handle possible server responses. The first one that came to mind was a request to delete an entry with a one-to-many relationship. For example:

```
def Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many books
end
```

Would be my Rails model. In my case, I don't allow the user to destroy libraries if they currently have books. The controller will respond with some sort of appropriate status, possibly a flag in the response header. The view then responds with a message to the user that the library still has books and cannot be deleted until the books are removed.

So my question is about exception handling. If I am to follow the oft paraphrased:

> Exceptions are for exceptional cases.

I am lead to the conclusion that this should not be an exceptional case because it is expected that the user will occasionally try to delete a library with books. Furthermore, the program accounts for this and has a message prepared for this case. Am I right to not consider this an exception?

For those of you that are deep into AngularJS, when do you actually use exceptions in practice?

Also, I think it's important to note that because of the asynchronous nature of the xhr requests I am using promise-chaining to handle the exceptions with `.then`, `.catch`, `$q.reject` etc. Which I'm still new to and don't fully understand its relationship to exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I also would not handle this as an exception. My method would be to log it with warning level on server side and show the error message in the view on client side.

I would not consider me an expert, but I think exceptions should never appear as feedback on client side if it is a productive application, because the user should not be forced to look into the console to search for errors.

If the error is a considered one like yours just show an error message.
If it is anchored in your methods and only appears in cases which should not happen during an usual use, you should throw an exception so you know what happened. But you should also show some feedback in the view for the user.